# Before npm install delete node_modules?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

Is it necessary to delete node_modules before executing an 'npm install' for a more reliable installation or does npm overwrite everything?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Npm definitely does not overwrite everything every time. It runs through a fairly complicated process that I won’t dive deep into here, but in general you should not need to delete `node_modules` every time. npm exists to handle this situation and generally will only download newly added or updated packages.

I will occasionally find myself in the need to completely remove the `node_modules` directory in the event that I have been add/removing/updating a large number of packages. Sometimes packages can get cached. But it’s not a common occurrence and I usually only recommend it when you notice a package appears out of date.

Comment: Does every git branch in a node app use the same modules?

Comment: Node_modules should never be committed to source control. So yes, switching branches would have nothing to do with node_modules, unless, of course, the npm packages in package.json differed from one branch to another. When that’s the case, you should be running `npm install` each time so that you have the correct modules installed